# CSS styling for lists in containers

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me in writing a CSS code which is more or less similar to this:

[image]

Comment: u should have tried something where is the code???

Comment: No, we're not going to do the work for you.

Comment: You are new so you don't know the format here. But next time please show an attempt at code and make a specific question.

Comment: @MattBall I should have put my own code which I have been trying but sorry I was not asking for the actual code but just for some suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jDFEr) should give you a starting point

[image]

They are basically containers with styled lists. Inside their is a heading which can be a `<h2>` or any heading or no heading but just a styled title. Remember to reset the margins from the `<ul>` and in the `<li>` use a background image for the arrows. Ideally you want that in a sprite sheet.

### HTML

```
<div class="link-container">
  <h2>Sales Reports</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sales By Customer</a>
    <li><a href="#">Sales By Item</a>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="link-container">
  <h2>Invoice Reports</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Invoice Aging</a>
    <li><a href="#">Invoice Details</a>
    <li><a href="#">Credit Note Details</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.link-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.link-container h2 {
  background-color: #abd5ea;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.link-container ul {
  font-size: 13px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.link-container ul li{
  background-image: url('http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC688534.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  border-bottom: #777 1px solid;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.link-container ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanx..That was exactly what i was intending to acheive..You made it so simple which helped me to grasp it quickly by your thorough explanation.